# Rotate an image each degree from 0° to 359° and save them

Tags: image, photoshop, autorotate

I have one image, is it possible in Photoshop to rotate it each degree from 0° to 359° ? and save them to each file per degree ? It's really a night mare to rotate it one by one.

Do you guys have any idea or any plug in can do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make an action!!

Open image in photoshop
Record acion = convert to smart object - rotate 1°- stop record (action ready to use)

the second image opened in the smart object las image.

do it - 359° .